# PostgreSQL Insert into Table A a Record for Each Record in Table B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables, `checklists`, `checklist_items` and `checklist_item_types`. I am wanting in my scheduled job to `INSERT` a record in `checklist_items` for every record in `checklist_item_types` that meets a criteria (`is_active` column being `true`).

Here is my `checklists` table:

```
id  checklist_date  notes
1   "2018-07-23"    "Fixed extra stuff"
2   "2018-07-24"    "These are some extra notes"
3   "2018-07-25"    "Notes notes"
```

Here is my `checklist_items` table, data reduced:

```
id  checklists_id  checklists_item_types_id  is_completed
1   1              1                         false
2   1              2                         true
3   1              3                         true
...
34  2              16                        true
35  2              17                        true
36  2              18                        true
```

And here is `checklist_item_types`, data reduced (for example assume all `is_active` are `true` except for 15):

```
id  description                        is_active
1   "Unlock Entrances"                 true
2   "Ladies Locker Room Lights"        true
3   "Check Hot Tubs (AM)"              true
...
15  "Water Softener Boiler Room"       false
16  "Water Softener Laundry"           true
17  "Check/Stock Fire Logs"            true
18  "Drain Steam Lines (4 locations)"  true
```

So when my job runs I want `checklist_items` to get, using examples above, 17 new records (18 `checklist_item_types` minus 1 because it's `false` for `is_active`).

The "new" `checklist_items`, after the job runs once would look like:

```
id  checklists_id  checklists_item_types_id  is_completed
1   1              1                         false
2   1              2                         true
3   1              3                         true
...
34  2              16                        true
35  2              17                        true
36  2              18                        true
---new data starting below---
37  3              1                         false
38  3              2                         false
39  3              3                         false
40  3              4                         false
41  3              5                         false
42  3              6                         false
43  3              7                         false
44  3              8                         false
45  3              9                         false
46  3              10                        false
47  3              11                        false
48  3              12                        false
49  3              13                        false
50  3              14                        false
51  3              16                        false
52  3              17                        false
53  3              18                        false
```

Comment: what's the challenge you are facing ? What all options did you try ? We strongly encourage documenting your attempt & challenges, before asking assistance in the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into checklist_items (checklists_id, checklists_item_types_id, is_completed)
    select 3, cit.checklists_item_types_id, false
    from checklist_item_types cit;
```

Comment: How do I go about getting the `checklists_id` to match up as well?

Comment: Your question doesn't explain how to get that id, which is why it is hard-coded.  Perhaps you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating classes to communicate with the database. Here is a portion of a class to extract your required checklist_item_types. As you can see, you need another class "DatabaseConn" in the database.php file to open connection to the database. You will need some PHP code to call this function and also the function to add to checklist_items table.

```
<?php
require_once("model/database.php");
class checklist_item_types extends DatabaseConn
{
...
    public function get_records_by_id_and_completed($starting_id, $is_completed) {
        global $dbConn;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM checklist_item_types 
           WHERE id >= $starting_id AND is_completed = $is_completed";
        try {
            $statement = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute();
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            $statement->closeCursor();
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
...
}
?>
```